# DispatcherObject on Non-UI Threads

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading

I would like to create a non-UI object model whose objects are thread-affined.  If I inherit from `Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject` in the WindowsBase assembly I can leverage a lot of good code for this.  However, I'm a little hesitant as it *feels* like I'm coupling my library to WPF.  But is WindowsBase *really* part of WPF?

I have already rolled my own Dispatcher and DispatcherObject implementation. It was a good learning experience, is relatively simple, and seems to work well.  But if others end up inheriting or using this code, they will have to familiarize themselves with it.  If I use the code from WindowsBase, I can just refer them to MSDN.

So I'm looking for recommendations.  Would you suggest inheriting from `DispatcherObject`, or would you consider it bad form?  Was the DispatcherObject intended to be used outside of WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are not coupling it to WPF.

I think it is in similar position to ObservableCollection (even though ObservableCollection is in System.dll) - it's most natural habitat is WPF, but it is not hard to think of use for it outside WPF.

By the way, you are not even coupling it to Microsoft CLR. Dispatcher [seems to be implemented in Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/WindowsBase/System.Windows.Threading) as well, unlike the rest of WPF - authors of Mono have stated that [WPF is not even planned to be supported](https://twitter.com/#!/migueldeicaza/status/43831625049587712).

I also find it slightly odd that you mention DispatcherObject and not Dispatcher. You are somehow using DispatcherObject without Dispatcher?